# VMWare can't reach sqlserver 2008 R2 from public ip

Tags: sql-server-2008, vmware

I set up a virtual server with VMWare running Windows Server 2008 R2.

The hosting machine is my desktop computer with windows 10.

I set up everything and internet connection on my server is working correctly and if I check `localhost` or `static ip` **on server side**, I see the IIS7 home page.

My problem appens when I try to reach this page with the public ip of my machine.
I checked on no-ip and also on websites which tells you the public IP of your desktop. Now I tryed to navigate to this ip but neither from the server itself, neither from hosting machine or external net I can find my site.

What I tryed:

- Disabled all firewalls on server
- Disabled all firewalls on hosting desktop pc
- Set up on VMWare the connection as *Bridge*

I also searched on the net but I don't really know how to make my server visible with his public ip.

Those are my VMWare settings:
[image]

If you need something else, ask freely.

Any help will be appreciated, thanks all.

Comment: 1) where does sql server come in to it? 2) does your network router allow the ports you want through, and forward them to the appropriate place? 3) does your isp allow them through? 4) the public ip will likely not work inside your local network, this is a security feature of routers. 5) can you ping the server over local IP?

Comment: @TZHX Thanks for the reply, you pointed me to the correct answer.. My internet connection doesn't allow the public ip. I requested a public ip address hoping they will give it to me asap. Thanks a lot, if you post the answer or something that can help others, I will accept it